# WebStorm does not suggest autocomplete based on TypeScript types for some reason

Tags: webstorm

Just started a fresh new React project, using WebStorm as my IDE.

Lets look at some type of material-UI typography 'varient' attribute:
[image]

For an unknown reason, WebStorm does not peek at these types:

[image]

*('no suggestions' is  written buy when I screenshot the message disappear)*

VSCode auto-suggest with no problems on this union type:

[image]

What's going on? I know for sure that these sort of suggestions worked previously in WebStorm (I'm using latest version).

This is the code:

```js
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Typography variant="">hello world, doing good?</Typography>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

[WEB-53199](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53199) is fixed in the upcoming 2021.3.2 update